# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit system freezes completely during browsing

Tags: 14.04

Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS from 12.04 LTS. After that my system freezes randomly when I am using Firefox. Then I have to restart the system to get rid of the system hang.

Comment: This is probably a graphics driver issue. Do the freezes usually happen on sites with videos or flash applets? There's also WebGL that can trigger such things, which is most prominently used by Google Maps.